# IE borders mess up when resizing height with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, border

I have a menu div which changes height dynamically, depending on the content.

The IE-only issue is that the border leaves a stain on the page when the menu div shrinks as shown in the attached image.

[image: IE-border trail]

Are there any CSS or jQuery hacks which could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try closing and reopening the dialog every time it is resized, sort like this:

```
$("#mydiv").dialog({
    resize: function(event, ui){
        $("#mydiv").dialog("close").dialog({height:ui.size.height});
    }
});
```